# windows phone 7 background service like android intent service

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new in windows phone 7. I want to know background servies like android intent service. Android intent services is run service one by one .If the services is completed,automatically stop this and run another servies .In windows phone 7 , I don't know how to do.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to do something comparable with an Intent in WP7.

The nearest thing would be a custom Launcher or Chooser. Creating these is not possible though.  :(

Maybe in the next version of the tools.